# DefaultTableModel Highlighting Clicked on Cells

Tags: java

I'm making a GUI simple calendar program. I am displaying a month view of the calendar with a DefaultTableModel and DefaultTableCellRenderer. My calendar is set up to highlight today's date. I would like for it to also highlight a user clicked on date with some other color. I have attached mouse listeners to each cell and am able to retrieve that date of those cells, but I do not know how to get the tblCalendarRenderer to update (at least not properly). I got it to sort of start highlighting some dates that are clicked with the same color, but it only does it like every other click and highlights the previous date I clicked on, not the current. It will also start highlighting multiple, and then refresh at some point. Could someone please tell me how to accomplish it correctly?

Here's some code:

```
public static void monthView(final int month, int year){
            //print month calendar

            int nod, som; //Number Of Days, Start Of Month

            //Clear table
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                    MyCalendarTester.mtblCalendar.setValueAt(null, i, j);
                }
            }

            if(initial){ // to make sure that the mouse listeners are only created once.
                initial = false;
                MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int rowEvent = MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getSelectedRow();
                        int colEvent = MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getSelectedColumn();

                        System.out.print(arrayOfMonths[month].toString() + " ");
                        MyCalendarTester.realDay = Integer.parseInt(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getValueAt(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.convertRowIndexToModel(rowEvent),
                                MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.convertColumnIndexToModel(colEvent)).toString());

                        System.out.print(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getValueAt(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.convertRowIndexToModel(rowEvent),
                                MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.convertColumnIndexToModel(colEvent)) + " ");
                        System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.currentYear);


                        //Apply renderers
                        MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.setDefaultRenderer(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getColumnClass(0), new tblCalendarRenderer());
                        MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getCellRenderer(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.convertRowIndexToModel(rowEvent), MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.convertColumnIndexToModel(colEvent));
                    }

                });
            //Draw calendar
            for (int i=1; i<=nod; i++){
                int row = new Integer((i+som-2)/7);
                int column  =  (i+som-2)%7;
                MyCalendarTester.mtblCalendar.setValueAt(i, row, column);

            }
            //Apply renderers
            MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.setDefaultRenderer(MyCalendarTester.tblCalendar.getColumnClass(0), new tblCalendarRenderer());

}

static class tblCalendarRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column){
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
                if (column == 0 || column == 6){ //Week-end
                    setBackground(new Color(255, 220, 220));
                }
                else{ //Week
                    setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
                }
                if (value != null){
                    if (Integer.parseInt(value.toString()) == MyCalendarTester.realDay && 
                            MyCalendarTester.currentMonth == MyCalendarTester.realMonth && MyCalendarTester.currentYear == MyCalendarTester.realYear){ //Today
                        setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 255));
                    }
                }
                setBorder(null);
                setForeground(Color.black);
                return this;  
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the code for highlighting go in the renderer code? The `selected` and `focus` boolean parameters could prove helpful here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yep! Now I feel stupid... Didn't realize that I could use those in an if statement in the renderer code.... oops Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to HovercraftFullOfEels! I just added:

```
        if(selected && value != null){
            setBackground(new Color(100,200,50));
        }
```

to the renderer.

Comment: That could work, 1+. Myself, I'd avoid magic numbers but would use Color constants, making it much easier to debug and modify my code.

Comment: It's a placeholder for now I'll probably declare some Color constants when I'm cleaning up my code after I get everything that I need to working.